# Discord bot does not mention msg.author.username

Tags: discord.js

I have been working on a Discord Bot for the last 5 days and noticed that my bot does not mention the msg.author.username I've been trying to figure this out for some time now and haven't found any solution to this problem.

Here is the code

```
client.on('message', gotMessage);

  function gotMessage(msg) {
    if (msg.channel.id == process.env.test_channel && msg.content === 'Hi') {
       msg.channel.send(`Hello ${msg.author.username}, how are you doing `)
      }
    }
```

Here is the error message

```
msg.channel.send(`Hello ${message.author.username}, `);
^TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined
```

Also to mention the code work fine yesterday and haven't had any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`msg.author.username` is the username of the user of type string (e.g. `hydrabolt`). For mention purpose you will need `msg.member` which represents the author of the message as a guild member.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your answer it worked! again thanks and have a nice day :)

Comment: Glad to help, if this answers your question, mark it as an answer.